# Find model based on jsonb nested data field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jsonb, postgresql-9.5

I use Ruby on Rails and Postgres 9.5.

In the database I have a table called `events`.

I want to find all events based on particular value in the data field.

`events.data` has the following possible json value:

```
{ 'transition' => { 'from' => 'bacon', 'to' => 'ham' } }
```

How can I build a query that will find an event with data => transition => from `bacon`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your model is called `Event`, you can do it like this:

```
Event.where("data -> 'transition' ->> ? = ?", 'from', 'bacon')
```

[Here is jsonb operators reference.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-OP-TABLE)

This query will return all events where `data.transition.from` is equal to `bacon`.

To DRY your queries, you can add it to the repository, e.g.:

```
# app/repositories/event_repository.rb

module EventRepository
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    scope :where_transition, ->(field, value) { where("data -> 'transition' ->> ? = ?", field, value) }
  end
end
```

After that include it in your model:

```
include EventRepository
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
Event.where_transition('from', 'bacon')
Event.where_transition('to', 'ham')
```